# implementacion ajax js en laravel 7

Tags: javascript, laravel, ajax

Quiero implementar una petición asíncrona con un código js que dejo a continuacion que me funciona bastante bien.

Este es el controlador:

```
public function index(){

    $id = auth()->id();     
    $biblioteca = books::where('user_id', $id)->get();

    return view('home.index', compact('biblioteca'));
}
```

En el blade tengo esto:

```
@foreach ($biblioteca as $libros)
              <tr>
                <th scope="row">
                  <b>{{ $libros-> Nombre}}</b>
                </th>

                <td>
                  <b>{{ $libros-> Lugar}}</b>
                </td>

                <td>
                  <b>{{ $libros-> Categoria}}</b>
                </td>

                <td>
                  <b>{{ $libros-> Ip}}</b>
                </td>

                <td>
                   <a href="#" onclick="ok();" class="btn btn-sm btn-primary">ok</a>                        
                </td>

              </tr>
              @endforeach
```

Codigo JS

```
function ok() {
  var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhttp.open("GET", "http://192.168.0.5/ok", true);
  xhttp.send();
};
```

Ahora paso a explicar donde esta el desafio, que rompiendome la cabeza no pude hacer andar. En la DB books, cada libro tiene su ip, al crearse cada boton para cada libro en la tabla (en el blade), necesito llamar a esa funcion js, y que la funcion tome el ip del libro que estoy cliqueando. Haciendo la llamada get asincrona (sin redirigirme a esa ip). gracias, si no me explique bien con gusto reformulare la pregunta. muchas gracias.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lo que puedes hacer es realizar una llamada ajax en tu funcion ok

seria algo como esto:

en el boton:

```
<a href="javascript:void(0)" id="{{ $libros->id}}" class="btn btn-sm btn-primary boton_url">ok</a>
```

y luego en la funcion:

```
    $(document).on('click', '.boton_url', function () {
       let id = this.id;
        $.ajax({
            url: 'url_',
            type: 'get',
            data: id,
            success: function (data) {
                var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
                xhttp.open("GET", data.url, true);
                xhttp.send();
            },
            error: function (data) {
                console.log(data);
            }
        })
```

Comment: gracias dani, genio